# Combining audio file and images and converting to video file in webapp - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, video, mp3, type-conversion

I have been thinking about a nice, little project. My plan is to make a website where users can upload their mp3's and pick some pictures, I'll combine the mp3's and pictures and convert them to a video format, this preferably in rails, my beloved hobbyist framework (though other languages are no problem).

Does anyone have an idea how to combine the mp3 and pictures and convert them to a video format?

Greetings,

Abel

Comment: Have you looked at this... http://rvideo.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems you can not convert files with rvideo, atleast not the way I want to..but it's a lead :)